# Flexbox grid - IE wraps too early

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

Working on a flexbox grid I ran into a problem, where IE would wrap too early.

```
flex: 0 1 33.33333%
```

That works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but only displays two items in a row in IE.

Answer (score 3):

You're hitting an IE bug -- IE doesn't seem to account for `box-sizing` when interpreting the `flex-basis` value. However, they do get it right when you add a layer of abstraction and use `flex-basis: auto` to pull in `width: [whatever]`.

So, I'd suggest just replacing this style:

```
flex: 0 1 33.33333%;
```

with this style:

```
flex: 0 1 auto;
width: 33.333333%;
```

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEvOWq

This updated style is equivalent in meaning to your old style (for a flex item in a horizontal flex container), and it works around this IE bug, so it should do the trick.

(NOTE: This IE bug & workaround are currently documented as ["entry #7" on Philip Walton's handy flexbugs page](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#7-flex-basis-doesnt-account-for-box-sizingborder-box).)

Answer (score 0):

```
flex: 0 1 100%;
max-width: 33.33333%;
```

Is a workaround, that seems to work in all browsers. Check out this pen in Chrome/FF and in IE http://codepen.io/rootman/pen/dPaLJE

Are there any pitfalls that I am missing? If not, I hope it proves useful! :)

Comment: Seems to be an IE bug with an interaction between `box-sizing:border-box` and `flex-basis`. Codepen demonstrating the bug more clearly: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azMzWK